# which is the fastest date compare way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a column which is date type, but the parameter passed in the procedure is a string, so can I convert this column to string or convert the passed parameter to date then compare them?

Comment: Why don't you pass a date parameter then?

Comment: The latter. Convert parameter to date. Or better yet, pass in a date and get rid of the string alltogether.

Comment: Think about converting once (string-date) or once per row (date-string), which one is probably more efficient?

Comment: Don't convert your `date` datatype to a `varchar`; you'll probably get very odd behaviour; especially if you use `BETWEEN`, `>` or `<`. For example, the statement `21/10/2012' > '01/01/2018'` is **true**.

Comment: why convert string to date then compare them is better?

Comment: In addition to my above comment, converting the value of your column would make the query non-SARGable as well. This will greatly increase the cost of the query.

Comment: because comparing date to date would give you proper result then comparing strings converted from date. In short should convert to date if you want to compare dates and you should convert to string if you want to compare strings.

Comment: Strings are *great* for interfacing with humans, when we have to print things on screens or accept input from keyboards. But ideally, shortly after input you *transform* from a string into an *appropriate* data type. (Similarly, for output, you use appropriate data types until as late as possible). By the time data is going to/from the database, there should be no sign of *strings* if there is a more appropriate data type to hold the data.

Comment: OK, right now the date column contains date and time, but I just want to compare the date part that means I would like to consider 2018-05-23 11:11:20 equals to 2018-05-23 13:01:10. so I will have to write the condition like this:   convert(date, date_column, 23) = convert(date, some_date_string, 23), right?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple to reason this one out:

If you keep it a string SQL will, for each row, have to convert the date(time) column's value to a string and *then* compare. On a table with millions of rows that will be an expensive operation since it needs to do this for every row.

If you convert the string parameter to a datetime SQL can do direct comparisons with the converted value on each row.

Besides the above which could've been reasoned quite simply when just stopping and thinking about it there are a lot of pitfalls like [Larnu1 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601112/which-is-the-fastest-date-compare-way/50601217#comment88211430_50601112); only equality will work (best-case), greater-than, less-than, between and such won't work as expected.

Also, a date(time) comparison will be a lot quicker since it's a single 8-byte<sup>*</sup> value that can be compared with a single instruction (or very few) on the CPU instead of having to iterate all chars in the string for comparison.

Look up [Sargeability](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/); another argument to convert to datetime.

Best is to get rid of the string alltogether and expect a datetime passed. This makes your interface convey what you need much more clearly (and also rules out problems with date/time conversions like 6/2/2020, is it Jun 2nd or Feb 6th or ...?).

<sup>*</sup> Depending on the exact datetime type you're using this may differ.

Answer (score 0):

**Converting the parameter to date is faster**

1. Date is an integer data type with a fixed length. Thus the comparison is faster except for very short strings.
2. Converting always takes time. Converting a value once is faster than converting a value n-times.

Additionally: Converting to string and comparing outright only lets you compare for equality or inequality. Not lesser than or greater than etc.